# Array list in kotlin not storing data after initialization

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to fetch data from the firebase realtime database and I am storing it in a list of User data class to display it in the recycler view. But the list is not storing any data. I tried to add some dummy data during initialization and that is working perfectly. But after initialization, it is not storing anything.
I tried with the mutable list too, but that is also not working.

The main fragment where I am retrieving the data:

```
class UserChatFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var mobileno: String
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_chat, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val session = sessionManager(context!!)
        mobileno = session.getLoginContact()
        val UserList = getusersdata()
        Chat_recyclerview.adapter = UsersAdapter(UserList)
        Chat_recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        contact.text = mobileno
    }

    private fun getusersdata(): List<User> {

        val list: = ArrayList<User>()

        val databaseReference =
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users").child("Connections")
                .child(mobileno)
        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    for (data: DataSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                        val userReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")
                            .child("Accounts").child(data.key!!)
                        userReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                                    val item = User(
                                        snapshot.child("name").value.toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("profilePicture").value.toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("phone").value.toString()
                                    )
                                    list.add(item)
                                }
                            }
                            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(context, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
        return list
    }
}
```

Adapter class:

```
class UsersAdapter(private val userList: List<User>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.UserViewHolder>() {

    class UserViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val mName: TextView = itemView.cardname
        val mImage: CircleImageView = itemView.cardprofilepicture
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserViewHolder {
        val itemView =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.cardview_chat, parent, false)
        return UserViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = userList[position]

//        Glide.with(UsersAdapter).load()
        Picasso.get().load(currentItem.profileimageurl).into(holder.mImage)
        holder.mName.text = currentItem.name
    }

    override fun getItemCount()=userList.size
}
```

No syntax error

Comment: instead of ArrayList, try to use MutableList. so it will be like: `val list: MutableList<User> = mutableListOf()`

Comment: I tried that but it's working same

Comment: ah I see,,, the `onDataChange` method is working asynchronously,, so instead of modifying local variable, you should modify class property.... move out the list into class property, and do changes it inside these methods, and dont forget to notify data changes to the adapter..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method to obtain the list `getUserList()` is asynchronous; meaning it needs to wait for firebase to produce results.

You can see this because you do `databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent...` meaning you're adding a listener that will be called in the future, not synchronously.

Your method (`getUserList`) creates a new list, and returns it (empty).

Later, your firebase callback is called and you modify the local list; it's already "too late".

As a "quick hack"  you can change the getUserList() method to something more like `fun fetchResultsAndInitializeAdapter()` (which is a little bit of a code smell because a function is doing "two things" but it should work). It doesn't return anything.

So inside the `fetchResultsAndInitializeAdapter` you can initialize the adapter after the list is populated:

```
                        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                            val list: List<xxx>

                            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                                val item = User(
                                    snapshot.child("name").value.toString(),
                                    snapshot.child("profilePicture").value.toString(),
                                    snapshot.child("phone").value.toString()
                                )
                                list.add(item)
                            }

                            adapter = YourAdapter(list)
                            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
                        }
```

Now, I wouldn't do this. I believe this database transaction and list mutation does not belong here, it belongs in a repo or a viewmodel that exposes a LiveData<List> that is observed by your Fragment/Activity, and when a value is emitted it is simply passed onto the Adapter.

But the whole firebase + list creation + etc. shouldn't be mixed with a Fragment's code in my opinion.

Comment: I changed my code to this [link](https://codeshare.io/5N6rkl) but still its not working

Comment: You're waiting for one callback (line 18 in that link), and then inside that onDataChange, you listen for ANOTHEr callback (line 24) `userReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent`. But you return the adapter `Chat_recyclerview.adapter = UsersAdapter(list)` in line 40, so nothing is added to the list at that point, because you need to wait for the userReference... you're still passing an empty list :)

Comment: You need to provide a repository (or viewmodel) and you need to subscribe and wait for those results. I don't have Firebase experience, but this is a typical problem that has nothing to do with Firebase per-se. This is a callback nesting of two callbacks, where the output is defined by both. For each item in the first stnapshot, you have to fetch the user, but you can't go iterating each "connections", you have to go one by one and WAIT for the user to be back before adding to the list...

Comment: By adding `adapter.notifyDatasetChanges()` it's working correctly now

Answer (score 0):

the `onDataChange` method is working asynchronously,, so instead of modifying local variable, you should modify class property.... move out the list into class property, and do changes it inside these methods, and don't forget to notify data changes to the adapter..

you need something like this:

```
class UserChatFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var mobileno: String
    val listUser: MutableList<User> = mutableListOf()  // move it out here..


...
... // TLDR
                            // somewhere on your code
                            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                                    val item = User(
                                        snapshot.child("name").value.toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("profilePicture").value.toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("phone").value.toString()
                                    )
                                    listUser.add(item)
                                    adapter.notifyDatasetChanges()
                                }
                            }
   ...
}
```